# Is there a dynamic Sql builder library for .Net?

Tags: .net, sql, ado.net, dynamic-sql

Something like this.

http://code.google.com/p/squiggle-sql/wiki/Tutorial.

This is required for cases where It is required to build complex sql from the user input from UI. Currently in the project I am working is using String Manipulation which looks ugly and is difficult to maintain.

Comment: in 2018 you can use https://sqlkata.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [DbExtensions](http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/), available as [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DbExtensions).

Comment: DbExtensions is easy to use. However, it has a few fundamental design problems. First, it doesn't have a much desire INSERT IGNORE INTO function. Secondly, it is very rigid. When one does INSERT_INTO, he cannot do INSERT_INTO({0}({1},{2}), tableName, col1, col2) because that will add single quotes around the parameters. Instead you have to use the overload and basically hardcode in the input string. Another example is doing the VALUES which you either have to do VALUES(some_string) or do VALUE({0} = {1}, col1, val1). With that said, it's not a bad library but it leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @SomeNewbie Post your comments [here](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/issues) and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to find a very good library for creating dynamic sql in .Net.

http://dynasql.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of (although that doesn't mean there definitely isn't).

What about Entity Framework?  It allows the query to be built up and translates that to SQL against entities:

```
customers.OrderBy(c => c.Name).Skip(10).Take(20)
```

Generates:

```
SELECT value c 
FROM NW.Customers AS c 
ORDER BY c.Name skip 10 limit 20;
```

Comment: The application I am working on is in .Net 2.0. So EF is not an option for me.

Comment: Can you use a full blown orm such as NHibernate?  It will give you the ability to build I queries through it'd Criteria API.

Comment: We are using nHibernate 1.2 in our application but this particular functionality has bypassed nHibernate for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Anything wrong with Linq-to-Sql?

```
var dc = new YourDataContext();
var query = dc.TableName.Where(x=>x.MatchesYourPredicate);
Console.WriteLine(dc.GetCommand(query).CommandText);
```

Comment: The project for which I needed that was .Net 2.0 project.

Comment: Also, the filtering elements are not always know

Comment: For me the table name is only known at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I always build my own...  it's quick and easy and you don't have to rely on 3rd-party libraries.  Plus it helps you become that little bit more intimate with SQL.

Comment: That's true if you're a programmer, but I can see that library being used to drive a GUI that allows non-programmers/data entry people to build generic queries against a database. They're never going to be able to do so *efficiently* but sometimes it's useful.

Comment: Do you mind sharing it?

Comment: Is it really that easy? How are you handling sub selects? Is there strong typing? Joining? Aliasing? Can you group items in a where clause so OR statements don't nullify the AND statements? I could go on.

Comment: Yes, it's quite easy - and you retain complete control of what's going on, which can help you better understand the approach you're taking and why you've taken that approach.