# Can I get a DbList from a string of the name of the entity?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

I am builing a ui query builder with Entity Framework. I was thinking of letting the user choose a base entity type from a drop down list of entities, then populate a grid view as test. If you select this entity, your basic result will be the contexts of this grid view. Later I will add the ability to 'Include' other entities and filter. But for now I can't even get the basics. I have a drop down of all entities. But I do not see how to get a generic list based on the name of the entity. I think I need to use reflection, but can't figure that out. I can get this easily if I hard code the entity type, but that does not solve my problem.

I have DbContext set up, using entity Framework 5, and want the results on a ASP .Net webforms page.

Comment: For what it's worth: I would not do this. You'll end up in a string jungle and painstaking maintenance when the database schema changes. Better use a specification pattern and strong typed service or repository methods. But if you insist you could use dynamics for instance.

Comment: I definitely see your point. Now though I am stuck. I want to make a way for users to design queries. How do I translate a user selection of say a client entity into an actual query?

Comment: You can try your luck with existing query builders, maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671321/is-there-a-dynamic-sql-builder-library-for-net) gets you on track.

Comment: DbExtensions looks interesting. Thanks for the tip.